# Add the results of a custom query into a do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to add the post list from a custom query

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
```

into the content of a `do_shortcode`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly, so I'm going to answer accordingly. For this to work, you'll need to add the complete custom query inside a shortcode. Have a look at the [**Shortcode API**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) how short codes work and how it is used.

One thing to remember though, the output from a shortcode should not be `echo`ed, but `returned`

I presume that you've used [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to construct your custom query

You can create your shortcode from this example

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_custom_query_shortcode' );
function my_custom_query_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

$the_query = new WP_Query( 'YOUR ARGUMENTS TO USE' );

 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

        <---YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS HERE--->

      endwhile;

     $myvariable = ob_get_clean();

     return $myvariable;

 endif;    

}
```

This is how your shortcode will be used in [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

```
echo do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Would you know how I can go about using an existing shortcode to do this? I want to use a accordion spoiler box thats part of a shortcode collection that is part of a plugin.

Comment: Please be specific when you post questions. Your comment is out of scope of your original question. That should have been in your question. I answered what you've asked.

Comment: Next time, please make sure that before you post a question that you know what you **exactly** need. All of us here answer questions voluntarily, and just like you, we all offer up our own time to help others like you.